# Excel VBA code is not supporting to save a PPT at custom location with custom name

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to write a short Excel VBA code which 1) create, 2) edit 3) save and 4) close a PowerPoint Presentation.

This can be done using the standard code which saves a file at a hard coded location. However, I am trying to write code in this way that it will pop-up two input boxes and will ask for your 1) custom name of file and 2) custom location where you want to save the file.

Code that I have trying to write is not giving any error message, but it is doesn't saving the file as well.

```
Sub Save_Presentation_at_custom_location()

Dim pPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set pApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pApp.Visible = True

Set pPres = pApp.Presentations.Add
pPres.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutTitle

Filename = Application.InputBox("FileName") & ".PPTX"
Path = Application.InputBox("Path") & "\"

pPres.SaveAs Filename:="Path" & "FileName", FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
pPres.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you saved the strings with *""*

Change:

```
pPres.SaveAs Filename:="Path" & "FileName", FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
pPres.Close
```

to

```
pPres.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName, FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
pPres.Close
```

Also your dimensions Filename, Path and pApp are not declared on the code you showed but I guess you did it in your real code

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and suggestion. It helped and my Presentations are being saved at desired custom location. And Yes, I have mentioned the dimensions in the real code....Thanks again